# Unable to install Visual Studio Community 2022

Tags: visual-studio-2022

Unable to install Visual Studio Community 2022. Getting the following error,

[image]

While trying to get more details of the error getting the following screenshot,
[image]

Please help me with installation.

Comment: Are you in an Active Directory environment?

Comment: Have you tried re-downloading the latest version again (17.7.4)?